# Logic gate design

Tags: logic, boolean-logic

I am trying to design a logic gate solution for discrete math homework.
Question is: "In a nuclear power station there are 4 sensors to indicate various warnings in the power plant. The sensors are
prone to generating false warnings so we want to design a logic circuit whose output is on (T) only when at
least two of the sensors are on (T). In order to save costs we want to design the circuit with as few logic gates
(AND, OR and NOT) are possible."

(a) Design a suitable logic gate matching the specifications.
(b) Use the corresponding logical proposition to describe the logical circuit you designed.
(c) Generate the truth table to verify that the circuit will operate as claimed.

So far i got this. http://prntscr.com/pc3955

But i don't think it is correct.

Would anyone care to inspect it and advise?

Comment: In your current setup, if A and D are both on, then the warning light stays off.

Comment: Yes. From what i can understand, it would need to be designed that for any combination of 2 inputs, the output  should be true.

Comment: Only thing not working in this configuration is Sensor A and D true and B and D.
 I don't know how to configure that setup.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a school homework, I don't think anyone will provide you with answers.

There are multiple ways of searching for the most simplified logical proposition, which in turn will give you a circuit with minimal logic gate.

Now, there are only 4 sensors indicated (4 variables) and one easiest way to deal with small amount of variables (< 6 variables) I like to use is *k map*, short form for Karnaugh Map.

[Here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/karnaugh-map-boolean-algebraic-simplification-technique/) is a quick search I got from google, spend some time looking over it. The key idea to capture here is *Product of Sum* (POS), *Sum of Product* (SOP) and Prime Implicant (how you group using k map).

Best of luck there mate !

Answer (score 0):

> But i don't think it is correct.

Indeed it's not correct.

> Would anyone care to inspect it and advise?

The combinational circuit you have shown is: AB+BC+CD

The combinational circuit you need must cover all combinations of two sensors, i. e.: AB+AC+AD+BC+BD+CD